# Example component compiles on laravel but not the new ones

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I've tried a new install on Laravel 5.5 and 5.4, I put my vue js component under a div `id="app"` and I put the example component that comes with the fresh install on the blade template and it works fine.

then I try to create a new one, I call it example2, I copy and paste the code from the example to make shure there are no errors in the code, I register the component in app.js under the example that comes predefined like that:

> Vue.component('example2', require('./components/Example2.vue'));

I run npm run dev, and I go to welcome, the example that came with laravel works but mine still doesn't work.

I've commented `window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';` with no success.

The thing that puzzles me more is that the example that comes with laravel works, I've looked at the docs for compiling assets but I've not found anything that I'm supposedly doing wrong, is there anything that I'm missing in the process of compiling those components?